# Should I have accepted the offer to double my credit?

Tags: credit-score, credit

I recently received an "invite" from my credit card company with a limited time offer to double my current credit limit.  That's right, double!  I didn't reply, and they later followed up with an email.

My primary rationale for not taking advantage of this generous offer is that I am trying to pay down my debt, and that kind of financial freedom would only spell trouble.

My main question is, would accepting their offer have a positive impact on my credit rating, given that they liked having me so much as a customer they wanted to give me more?

Answer (score 5):

In most cases it is going to help you as long as you don't USE it. A big part of your credit score is what % of your available credit you are using, increasing the denominator of that ratio will help that factor of your score.

it was mentioned in another answer that having too much credit can hurt your score, but I am not so sure about that. Even if it is true, I think the impact would be trivial.

**Update**
Here is a rough breakdown of what comprises your Fair Isaac credit score:
35 percent of the score is based on your payment history
30 percent of the score is based on outstanding debt.
15 percent of the score is based on the length of time you've had credit.
10 percent of the score is based on new credit (new accounts temporarily decrease score).
10 percent of the score is based on the types of credit you currently have.

The exact calculation is a trade secret, so we really don't know every factor, so consider these rough estimates and know that there are other factors. However, given the relative weight of these, it doesn't leave much room for things like total available credit.

Source: [HowStuffWorks.com](http://money.howstuffworks.com/personal-finance/debt-management/credit-score1.htm):

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, I hear, having more of your credit "free" and unused is beneficial to your credit rating, but having too much credit in total is bad. So it's sort of a balancing act.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most important thing is that it doesn't hurt you to *not* take the offer.  Especially if you don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

More credit is more borrowing power and yes that has a say in your credit score.  But if you think you might be tempted to abuse this, then the decision you took is correct.  If you keep paying your cc bills on time, don't worry, you'll soon receive similar offers in future.

Comment: You are absolutely correct - always remember that we're human, and if you think you'll be more likely to spend more money with a higher credit limit, you've made the right decision to turn down the increase.  Look at it this way: if instead of paying down your debt, after taking the increase in credit, you continued to charge more money onto credit cards, how much more money would you lose? (not to mention your debt/income ratios might not increase if you spent enough)